# [JADE]How to send data from agent to a simple object (POJO class)

Tags: java, agents-jade

JADE beginner, I can make a communication  between agents and also send data from an object to an agent using the `putO2AObject()` method of the `AgentController` class.

```
AgentController myAgentController = myContainer.getAgent("Test");
Person p1 = new Person("Person1", 0);
myAgentController.putO2AObject (p1, false);
```

My question is about the reverse, i.e. how can I send data from an agent to an object (not an agent)?. In other-words, I want my agent which gets a result at the end of his treatment?. I am really stuck and I need your help!.

Thank you.

Comment: Just give the agent a reference to your POJO and call the appropriate methods? Make sure you're taking care of synchronizing the requests if you want more than one agent to call the same method.